# How to trigger tab using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have to open table based on the query string, i have tried few thing but it doesn't seem to work

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygyzLX

```
if (tabid == "tabD3") {
    $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('active');
    $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(3) a').trigger("click");
    // $('a.#tabD3').trigger("click");
}
```

`$('.donate-tab li:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('active');` higlight the tab but doesn't show the content.

Below code doesn't make any difference

```
$('.donate-tab li:nth-child(3) a').trigger("click");
// $('a.#tabD3').trigger("click");
```

Comment: in the codepen there doesn't seem to be any content for any of the tabs, and I can't see any click events defined...so what do you hope to achieve by triggering them? You've tagged the question with "jquery-ui tabs" but I don't see any evidence that you're actually using that plugin.

Comment: i have updated the fiddle

Comment: it still doesn't use jqueryui tabs, and there still aren't any click events. Nor is there any CSS to show/hide the content. What are you actually trying to achieve? You talk about opening tables from a query string, but then the code is all about triggering non-existing click events on some very rudimentary home-made tab code. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using one of the tables from this theme http://minth.amazyne.com/v-1.6/shortcode-tabs.html but i am not able to find how or wher ei sthe function to trigger event for tabs so that i can work with it

Comment: that page is using bootstrap and lightbox, which are likely to be providing the tabs functionality unless the creator has written their own. So your jquery-ui tabs tag is wrong and you should remove it. Scraping code from other people's websites is never as simple as it looks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to make it work with following script

```
 var getQueryString = function (field, url) {
            var href = url ? url : window.location.href;
            var reg = new RegExp('[?&]' + field + '=([^&#]*)', 'i');
            var string = reg.exec(href);
            return string ? string[1] : null;
        };

        var tabid = null;
        tabid = getQueryString('tab'); // returns 'chicken'
        if (tabid !=null)
        {
            $('.donate-tab li').removeClass('active');
            $('.tab-content > .tab-pane').removeClass('active');

            if (tabid == "tabD1") {
                $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(1)').toggleClass('active');
                $('.tab-content #tabD1').toggleClass('active');
            }
            if (tabid == "tabD2") {
                $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(2)').toggleClass('active');
                $('.tab-content #tabD2').toggleClass('active');
            }
            if (tabid == "tabD3") {
                $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(3)').toggleClass('active');
                $('.tab-content #tabD3').toggleClass('active');
            }
            if (tabid == "tabD4") {
                $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(4)').toggleClass('active');
                $('.tab-content #tabD4').toggleClass('active');
            }
            if (tabid == "tabD5") {
                $('.donate-tab li:nth-child(5)').toggleClass('active');
                $('.tab-content #tabD5').toggleClass('active');
            }

        }
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use switch instead of multiple if statements?

Comment: @jazzgot, Agree with you there may be a better way to optimize it further